# Pushing projects to different GIT repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-extensions

in my Visual Studio 2013 I have a **solution** with a handful **projects**. Among others, I include a project where I have stored classes that I use in different projects. Those projects are located in different directories on my hard drive.

- Solution X

  - Project 1
  - Project with common classes (different folder)
  - Project with classes to deal with Sparql (different folder)
  - Project with Plugin contract Interfaces
  - ...

I use the Visual Studio AddIn **Git Extensions** for source control. Now I want to push each project to a **different** repository. When I try to add a new git repository for one project (rightclick the project > sourcecontrol > git > commit), it always pushes the whole solution (and pastes all projects in the local folder of that project).

With svn it was no problem to push to different repositories, but I can't find out, how to do this with Git (Extensions)

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

svn gets that nice facility with tradeoffs that hurt in other ways.

If you want to slice a subdirectory's history, do

```
git branch sliceme
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter path/to/that/subdir \
        -- --full-history sliceme \
        -- path/to/that/subdir
```

The first `--` separates filter-branch specs from the rev-list args used to generate the commits that feed your new history, the second `--` separates rev-list's options and commit-set boundaries from the path filters it uses to skip uninteresting commits.